# Ускорить код Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Решение задачи на сайте Codewars не проходит проверку по времени. Там на форуме вроде кто то писал что делал на python. значит у него задача прошла по времени.

----- текст условия -----

Пирамиды восхитительны! И в архитектурном, и в математическом смысле. Если у вас есть компьютер, вы можете возиться с пирамидами, даже если вы в это время не в Египте. Например, рассмотрим следующую задачу. Представьте, что у вас есть пирамида, построенная из чисел, как здесь:

```
   /3/
  \7\ 4 
 2 \4\ 6 
8 5 \9\ 3
```

Вот и задача...
Предположим, что «скольжение вниз» — это максимальная сумма последовательных чисел от вершины к основанию пирамиды. Как видите, самое длинное «скольжение вниз »3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23
Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы написать функцию, которая принимает представление пирамиды в качестве аргумента и возвращает ее « самое большое скольжение вниз» . Например:

- With the input `[[3], [7, 4], [2, 4, 6], [8, 5, 9, 3]]`
- Your function should return `23`.    (https://www.codewars.com/kata/551f23362ff852e2ab000037/train/python)
  ----- мое решение ---

```
def longest_slide_down(pyramid):
    def f2(a, b):
        return pyramid[a][b] + max(f2(a + 1, b), f2(a + 1, b + 1)) if a < l else pyramid[a][b]
    l = len(pyramid) - 1
    return f2(0, 0)
```

решает всё правильно, не проходит по времени(

Comment: Вставьте `@functools.cache` перед `def f2...`.

Comment: Мемоизация должна спасти при такой неприятной рекурсии.

Comment: @Harry, рекурсию можно вывернуть. Будет динамика bottom-top.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Это второй вариант того же ДП...

Comment: Офигеть! @functools.cache ну просто очень помогла! время первого теста сократилось с 11 мс до 0,2 мс. Спасибо большое всем!!!

Comment: А это — `@functools.cache` — по сути и есть мемоизация, просто не на уровне программы, а на уровне языка.